# stuck in MySQL/MariaDB placeholders limit when convert to excel - laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel

I have this query to get an array to convert to Excel:

```
if($sfname=='ALL'){
$st_outlet_reg = Sfs::wherebetween('created', [$datefrom, $dateto])
                        ->when($cluster, function($query, $cluster) {
                        $query->where('cluster', $cluster);
                        })->get();
}

nomor = 0;
        foreach ($st_outlet_reg as $key => $value) {
      $nomor++;
            $i= $key+2;

            $sheet->cell('A'.$i, $sfname)->setFontSize('10');
            $sheet->cell('B'.$i, $value['outlet_id'])->setFontSize('10');
            $sheet->cell('C'.$i, $value['nama_outlet'])->setFontSize('10');
            $sheet->cell('D'.$i, $value['created'])->setFontSize('10');
            $sheet->cell('E'.$i, $value['msisdn'])->setFontSize('10');

            $sheet->cell('A'.$i, function($cell1) {
            $cell1->setBorder('thin', 'thin', 'thin', 'thin')->setAlignment('center');  });
            $sheet->cell('B'.$i, function($cell1) {
            $cell1->setBorder('thin', 'thin', 'thin', 'thin')->setAlignment('center');  });
            $sheet->cell('C'.$i, function($cell1) {
            $cell1->setBorder('thin', 'thin', 'thin', 'thin')->setAlignment('center');  });
            $sheet->cell('D'.$i, function($cell1) {
            $cell1->setBorder('thin', 'thin', 'thin', 'thin')->setAlignment('center');  });
            $sheet->cell('E'.$i, function($cell1) {
            $cell1->setBorder('thin', 'thin', 'thin', 'thin')->setAlignment('center');  });

        }
```

number of rows from array should be 
[image]

and excel download results only 65k rows [image]

how to solve this

Comment: Is this limit produced by Excel format?

Comment: placeholder limit by mariaDB @GenoChen